# The value of stored properties and computed properties in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, properties, computed-properties

There is a computed property `computedArray` and a stored property `storedArray` in my programme, both of which get values from `DataController.shared.updateArray(withCurrentTimestamp: DataController.currentTimestamp)`

The value of `currentTimestamp` changes over time, but when I print out `DataController.shared.computedArray` and `DataController.storedArray`, the result of `DataController.shared.computedArray` changes with `currentTimestamp`, while `DataController.storedArray` never changes. what's the reason of it?

```
struct DataController {

    static let shared = DataController()

    var computedArray: [TimeInterval] {
        get {
            DataController.shared.updateArray(withCurrentTimestamp: DataController.currentTimestamp)
        }
    }
    
    static var storedArray = DataController.shared.updateArray(withCurrentTimestamp: DataController.currentTimestamp)

}
```

Comment: `storedArray ` is computed only one time, while `computedArray` is computed each time you access it

Comment: Another thing to note is that arrays are value types, which means every time you update an array, it creates and returns a new array. That means that although you’re getting the shared array in the computed variable, you’re still returning a new array. The shared array remains unchanged.